# layout display height issue on rotation mode

Tags: android, listview, layout, rotation

i create a app with some forms, they display right i want, the problem is on rotate screen, the form width it's ok but the layout height i have a issue because it don't display all items of the layout, trying to find a solution i put a scrollview for the linear layout, it works but, some of this forms have listviews inside, so the listviews scroll property has been blocked by the scrollview and finally i can't display all the layout info. I want to know if some one knows a solution for this issue and can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow below steps.

1) create a folder in res directory as **res/layout-land**.

2) suppose you have main.xml layout in res/layout folder.

3)Create one layout name main.xml into **res/layout-land** folder, name this layout as main.xml. design you UI as you want to show to the user in Landscape mode.

Now when you run your app and change Orientation . system automatically called main.xml according to the Orientation, SUppose phone is in Landscape mode, then it will show main.xml of layout-land folder

[see this example](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/android-layouts-supporting-orientation/)